# Angular 2 save file from Nodejs

Tags: node.js, angular, http

I have the snipped in NodeJS to try to do a download from my server.

```
router.post("/download", function(req, res, next) {
  console.log(req);
  filepath = path.join(__dirname, "/files") + "/" + req.body.filename;
  console.log(filepath);
  res.sendFile(filepath);
});
```

This is my Angular 2 code:
**Component.ts**

```
  download(index) {
    var filename = this.attachmentList[index].uploadname;
    this._uploadService
      .downloadFile(filename)
      .subscribe(data => saveAs(data, filename), error => console.log(error));
  }
```

**Service.ts**

```
export class UploadService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private loginService: LoginService) {}
  httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      responseType: "blob"
    })
  };

  downloadFile(file: string): Observable<Blob> {
    var body = { filename: file };
    console.log(body);
    return this.http.post<Blob>(
      "http://localhost:8080/download",
      body,
      this.httpOptions
    );
  }
```

In my HTML response I get the file correctly recording to my browser's network inspection tool. However Angular is trying to parse the response into a JSON object which obviously doesn't work since the response is a blob.

The error I get is this:

> Unexpected token % in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse ()
>   at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad angular 2

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You've added `responseType` as a header, but it shouldn't be. It should just be within the `httpOptions` object, not the `headers` object

Comment: @user184994 It worked at the begginning but when I recompile it gives me a compilation error.

"ERROR in src/app/services/upload.service.ts(25,7): error TS2345: Argument of type '{ headers: HttpHeaders; responseType: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }; observe?: "body"; params?: Ht...'.
  Types of property 'responseType' are incompatible.
    Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"json"'."

Answer (score 0):

Try the following http options:

```
{
    responseType: 'blob',
    observe:'response'
}
```

You will then get a response of type `HttpResponse<Blob>`, so doing data.body in your service will give you the blob that you can pass to saveAs.

You can find more info on observe here:

https://angular.io/guide/http#reading-the-full-response

Answer (score 0):

I solved that, in service code I deleted the  after the post because it forced my return get a binary file, and not a JSON. Now the code it's like that:

```
  downloadFile(file: string): Observable<Blob> {
    var body = { filename: file };
    console.log(body);
    return this.http.post<Blob>(
      "http://localhost:8080/download",
      body,
      this.httpOptions
    );
  }
```

Thank you all.